# string array of objects - sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit

I have an array of names of sksprite nodes. i need to make a new array and put the name from the last array but the sprite node that is closest to (tilt - name of another node) will be first in the array And so on. 
if I didn't explain my self clear enough tell me. please if anyone know how to do it. write here.
thanks

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Show what you have tried and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: i don't know how to do it. so i have no code to show.

Comment: When you are addressing a comment to someone, do it like this @rmaddy. Otherwise the person will not get a notification. Secondly, your question is not very clear. What exactly does your current array hold? The actual nodes? Just the names of nodes? What is the reference point when you say "node that is closest"? To what, another node? A touch? Something else? Again "closest" means what? A circle? Just the right, left, up down? You have to be specific and think your question out for others to understand it. This is especially important if you are not posting any code.

Comment: @sangony. the array holds the names of nodes. i need to organize the array from the closest nodes to the most far one. i have another node that from it i want to check the distance in order to organize the array.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort an array of nodes based on their distance from a given point ?

Comment: @prototypical. yes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said previously, your question lacked some specifics in exactly how this is to be implemented. I have made my code somewhat generic to be adaptable to pretty much any scenario you might have in mind.

I used the touch location coordinates as a starting point to calculating distances to the 4 nodes on screen. Click anywhere on the screen and a list will print with the 4 node names in order of distance.

There's probably a better way of sorting this but I decided on the quick and dirty way.

```
#import "GameScene.h"
@implementation GameScene {
    SKSpriteNode *node0;
    SKSpriteNode *node1;
    SKSpriteNode *node2;
    SKSpriteNode *node3;
    NSMutableArray *nodeArray;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    nodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    node0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
    node0.name = @"red";
    node0.position = CGPointMake(300, 300);
    [self addChild:node0];
    [nodeArray addObject:node0];

    node1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
    node1.name = @"blue";
    node1.position = CGPointMake(450, 500);
    [self addChild:node1];
    [nodeArray addObject:node1];

    node2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
    node2.name = @"yellow";
    node2.position = CGPointMake(100, 400);
    [self addChild:node2];
    [nodeArray addObject:node2];

    node3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
    node3.name = @"green";
    node3.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
    [self addChild:node3];
    [nodeArray addObject:node3];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

        NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for(SKSpriteNode *object in nodeArray) {
            float xDistance = fabsf(touchLocation.x - object.position.x);
            float yDistance = fabsf(touchLocation.y - object.position.y);
            NSString *totalDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",(xDistance+yDistance)];

            [myDict setValue:totalDistance forKey:object.name];
        }

        float lowestValue = 999999.0;
        NSMutableString *lowestName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        for (int i=0; i<[nodeArray count]; i++) {

            for (NSString *key in myDict) {

                if([[myDict objectForKey:key] floatValue] < lowestValue) {
                    lowestValue = [[myDict objectForKey:key] floatValue];
                    [lowestName setString:key];
                }
            }

            [myArray addObject:[NSString stringWithString:lowestName]];
            [myDict removeObjectForKey:lowestName];
            lowestValue = 999999.0;
        }

        NSLog(@"values: %@",myArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: @100tomer - No problem. If the code answered your question, please check it as an answer.